# Removing Edge colors in Cartopy heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am attempting to plot a heatmap showing the density of lightning using python's cartopy and matplotlib libraries.

I have roughly followed the code here [Cartopy Heatmap over OpenStreetMap Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50611018/cartopy-heatmap-over-openstreetmap-background) . However, my plot shown below contains solid lines around each transparent bin, which is my problem. The other plot is the same code with random numbers.  An ideal solution would be to not display the lines at all, or for the lines to match the bin's face color with the correct transparency.  I've done a fair amount of trial and error to remove them in addition to reading some matplotlib documentation. According to the 2d-histogram [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html) , I should be plotting a [QuadMesh](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh) object.  You should be able to set the linewidth to 0, or have the edgecolor set to none in the QuadMesh.  In my code below,  I tried doing that yet the lines still persist.  I've also tried the pcolormesh as well with the same result.
[image: The Heatmap]
[image: Second Dataset with Random Numbers]

Here is my code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt
import numpy as np
import random


#xsize and ysize are integers and lons, lats are 1d numpy arrays of longitude and latitude.
def testDensity(xsize, ysize, lons, lats):
    #Some code below follows example 
    #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50611018/cartopy-heatmap-over-openstreetmap-background

    request = cimgt.OSM()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(xsize,ysize),subplot_kw=dict(projection=request.crs), dpi=200)
    extent = [-126,-118,41,44]
    ax.set_extent(extent)
    ax.add_image(request,8)

    xynps = ax.projection.transform_points(ccrs.Geodetic(), lons, lats)#
    print(xynps, type(xynps))

    #Create 2-d histogram
    histogram = ax.hist2d( xynps[:,0] , xynps[:,1] ,cmap='jet', bins=100, zorder=1,alpha=0.5,edgecolors="none",linewidth=0 )
    print(histogram[3], dir(histogram[3]) )
    histogram[3].set_linewidth(0.0)
    histogram[3].set_edgecolor("none")
    #histogram:(frequency, xedges, yedges, image QuadMesh)

    #ax.pcolormesh(histogram[1], histogram[2], histogram[0], cmap = 'jet', alpha=0.5,edgecolors="none")
    cbar = plt.colorbar(mappable=histogram[3], ax=ax , shrink=0.5, format='%.1f1' )
    cbar.solids.set_rasterized("True")#Removes lines from colorbar
    cbar.solids.set_edgecolor("face")
    plt.savefig("densityTest.png", bbox_inches="tight")



#Generate random dataset
for i in range(0,800):
    lon = random.randrange(41,44) + random.random()
    lat = random.randrange(-126,-118) + random.random()
    lons.append(lon)
    lats.append(lat)
lons = np.array(lons)
lats = np.array(lats)

testDensity(9,34, lons, lats)
```

Comment: please, provide `lats, lons` so that we can test. It would be nice if they were small values: I tried the values on the link you posted, it easily surpassed 11GB of RAM :|

Comment: @David_sd I edited the post and added some code to generate random numbers.  The data in the image isn't the problem.  It's the lines around the bins I am trying to get rid of in pyplot/matplotlib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem seemed to be rendering as raphael suggested.  I ended up installing the required libraries in conda and the problem seems to have been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the problematic results you showed us because of errors in your code. But once I correct the errors in the code and run. I get a good result as shown below.

The modified code:

```
def testDensity(xsize, ysize, lons, lats):
    # Some code below follows example 
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50611018/cartopy-heatmap-over-openstreetmap-background (That's my another answer)

    request = cimgt.OSM()
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(xsize,ysize),subplot_kw=dict(projection=request.crs), dpi=200)
    extent = [-126, -118, 41, 44]
    ax.set_extent(extent)
    ax.add_image(request, 8)

    xynps = ax.projection.transform_points(ccrs.Geodetic(), lons, lats)

    #Create 2-d histogram
    # histogram = ax.hist2d(xynps[:,0],xynps[:,1],cmap='jet',bins=100,zorder=1,alpha=0.5,edgecolors="none",linewidth=0)
    #This produces the same result, but shorter.
    histogram = ax.hist2d( xynps[:,0], xynps[:,1], cmap='jet', bins=100, zorder=1, alpha=0.5)

    # (Why use these code?)
    #histogram[3].set_linewidth(0.0)
    #histogram[3].set_edgecolor("none")
    #ax.pcolormesh(histogram[1], histogram[2], histogram[0], cmap = 'jet', alpha=0.5,edgecolors="none")
    # cbar = plt.colorbar(mappable=histogram[3], ax=ax , shrink=0.5, format='%.1f' )
    # cbar.solids.set_rasterized("True")#Removes lines from colorbar
    # cbar.solids.set_edgecolor("face")

    # ... when this produces good result.
    cbar = plt.colorbar(histogram[3], ax=ax, pad=0.03, aspect=28, shrink=0.26, format='%.1f')  # h[3]: image
    plt.savefig("densityTest.png", bbox_inches="tight")
    plt.show()

#Generate random dataset
lons = []
lats = []

for i in range(0,800):
    lat = random.randrange(41,44) + random.random()
    lon = random.randrange(-126,-118) + random.random()
    lons.append(lon)
    lats.append(lat)

lons = np.array(lons)
lats = np.array(lats)

#testDensity(9,34, lons, lats)
testDensity(10,16, lons, lats)
```

The output plot:

[image: heatmap_on_streetmap]

Comment: It's interesting since your code works on my Windows anaconda environment with cartopy 0.18 and matplotlib 3.5.1 .  However, on my linux system with matplotlib 3.3.4 , it's still showing the gridded lines in my post above.  I should also note I tried something like your solution before I added all the other code you commented out.  I was reading the docs and simply trying code I thought would remove the lines.

Comment: I guess this is a rendering issue... it might be related to the matplotlib backend you're using... (It's somewhat related to this: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2823)